# How to add a dynamic image to a specific cell in a table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is code that I'm using to add specific input values that a user enters in a modal, to a table using JQuery, however I am struggling with inputting the image to the table, the user would select the image they want using a file form input which uses the ID of `#insert-image`. This is the code I have so far which doesn't work:

```
$("#btnAdd").on('click', function() {
  if ($("#insert-image").val() !== '' && $("#insert-name").val() !== '' && $("#insert-surname").val() !== '') {
    var imagePrep = $("#insert-image").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
    let row = '<tr> <td>' + "image" + '</td> <td>' + $("#insert-name").val() + '</td> <td>' + $("#insert-surname").val() + '</td> <td>' + "edit" + '</td> <td>' + "delete" + '</td> </tr>'
    $('tbody').append(row);
    $('td:contains("image")').html("<img src="images/imagePrep" alt="selected-image">").addClass("text-center");
    $('td:contains("edit")').html("<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>").addClass("text-center edit edit:hover")
    $('td:contains("delete")').html("<i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>").addClass("text-center delete delete:hover").attr("id", "btnDelete").on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent('tr').remove();
    });
  }
});
```

So basically the line in question is this:

```
$('td:contains("image")').html("<img src="images/imagePrep" alt="selected-image">").addClass("text-center");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was fix the quotation marks In order to add the `imagePrep` variable to the `tag`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
$('td:contains("image")').html("<img src=" + imagePrep + " alt='selected-image'>").addClass("text-center");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to add event listeners to listen to events that fires once an image is selected on an HTML `input` element.

Once the image is selected, you can read it's data and render it to the client-side:

```
function readImage(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            $('td:contains("image")').find('img').attr('src', evt.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Bind your `input` to the above function will change the `src` attribute of the `img` element located under `td:contains("image")`.